# Simple .on('keydown') jQuery event not responding until next key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm making a page for a friend and I have a hidden text field and when the user types the text is transposed into a div so that it looks like they're typing on the screen rather than in an input field.

Here is a link to the page: http://merkd.com/godis.php

Here is the function that I use to respond to the key strokes:

```
$('#hiddenInput').keydown(function() {
    var input = $('#hiddenInput').val();
    var html = '<div style="float: left;">'+input+'</div><div id="cursor">|</div>';
    $('#typingArea').html(html);
});
```

The text-field is visible right now so that you can see the problem. When text is entered or deleted, it doesn't respond until the next keypress. So if I type a single letter, nothing shows up until I type the next letter.

I looked at the jQuery `.on()` documentation but I couldn't find anything on this. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. I know it should be in a separate question, but is there an easy way to make a text-field always in focus? I want to make it so that no matter where the user clicks or whatever, if they type, the text will still show up.

Comment: On `keydown` no letter has appeared yet…

Comment: Your second question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229563/force-focus-on-one-element-with-an-exception-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.keyup()` event because when you first press (keydown), the letter is never typed so the `var html` is getting previous value. For second part you can bind `keypress` event in `document` to focus your input field.